# Neo4j query taking long time

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher, query-optimization, py2neo

I am currently working on a social media site which exactly the same in terms of users' timeline, like user can follow, create, share the posts, block, unblock, etc. So for that, we have created 2 types of labels "User" and "Post" and have several relations like follow, block, private, etc.
currently, we have approximately 41000 nodes and 650000 relationships.

Hardware conf:
8 gb ram
2 core
50 GB HDD

1 Master and 2 Slave

and using the following query to get the users' timeline

```
MATCH (n:User {user_id:'12129bca-9b90-44c9-aae8-d80e61f9c342',is_active:'1'}),(p:Post{is_deleted:'0'}),(po:User{user_id:p.owner_id})
                  WHERE (p.post_type = '1' OR p.post_type = '4')  WITH n,p,po 
                WHERE po.is_active='1' AND  (n)-[:CREATED{own_status:'1'}]->(p) OR
                (n)-[:FOLLOWS{follow_status:'1'}]->(:User{is_active:'1'})-[:CREATED{own_status:'1'}]->(p)
                OR (n)-[:FOLLOWS{follow_status:'1'}]->(:Keyword{is_deleted:'0'})-[:KEYWORD]->(p)
                WITH n,p,po
                OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[fr:FOLLOWS]->(po)
                WHERE fr.follow_status='1' WITH p,n,po,fr
                WHERE NOT ((n)-[:FOLLOWS{is_blocked:true}]->(po) OR (n)-[:FOLLOWS{is_mute:true}]->(po)) WITH p,n,po,fr
                WHERE NOT (n)<-[:FOLLOWS{is_blocked:true}]-(po) WITH p,n,po,fr
                WHERE (fr is not null and toInteger(po.is_private) <= 1 AND po.user_id <> n.user_id)
                OR (toInteger(po.is_private) <= 1 AND po.user_id = n.user_id)
                OR (toInteger(po.is_private) = 0 AND  po.user_id <> n.user_id) WITH p,n,po
                RETURN p,po,SIZE(()-[:LIKED]->(p)) as likecount,
                        SIZE((n)-[:LIKED]->(p)) as likestatus,count(*) as postcount
                ORDER BY p.created_at DESC
                SKIP 0 LIMIT 10
```

This query takes more than 10 sec. which is too high

Here is Profile of the above query

[image]

Here is the index list
[image]

Can anybody suggest where am I doing wrong?

Comment: How many of each Node type are there (specifically Post nodes but all metrics would help). How many of those have a type of 1 or 4?

Comment: The "Post" nodes approx 40000 and "User" nodes approx 2000.

Comment: How many Post nodes have type 1 or 4?

Comment: There is two type of posts image post and videos post. So the "type" 1(image post) is approx 34000 and "type" 4(video post) is approx 6000

Comment: What's the connection between the owner of a post (as specified by the ownerId property) and the :CREATED relationship?

Comment: I'm not sure your results are correct here, notably some of your aggregations. Can you give a verbal explanation of what your returned values are supposed to represent?

Comment: @InverseFalcon, I  am trying to get the users' timeline on the basis of his/her follow relationship just like Instagram. For eg, if A follows B, B follows C, so whenever C do some activity,  A should get on his/her timeline.

Comment: HDD is a bottleneck. Get fast ssds.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get a user's timeline, I would think you'd start with the specific user, then connect to other nodes via the relationships you're interested in. The current query isn't taking advantage of pattern matching or the connected nature of a graph database.

The first match statement of the query as it's currently written finds a specific user, then all Post nodes that have the property is_deleted:'0' and then all User nodes that are connected to any of the Post nodes. Searching this way is giving you more database hits (54,984) in the first middle Expand(All) than there are nodes in the database (41,000).

Where you should get the most lift in optimizing this query is to focus your search on the single user then expand out from there using the relationships:

```
MATCH (n:User {user_id:'12129bca-9b90-44c9-aae8-d80e61f9c342',is_active:'1'})-[r]-(p:Post{is_deleted:'0'})
```

This will match the user and all qualifying posts connected to the user via a relationship. Note, if a user isn't connected to any qualifying posts, there won't be any matches even if that user does exist in the database.

If you only want to include certain relationship types, you can specify that in this first MATCH statement like this:

```
MATCH (n:User {user_id:'12129bca-9b90-44c9-aae8-d80e61f9c342',is_active:'1'})-[r:CREATED|FOLLOWS|KEYWORD]-(p:Post{is_deleted:'0'})
```

Or you can put it in the WHERE clause like this:

```
MATCH (n:User {user_id:'12129bca-9b90-44c9-aae8-d80e61f9c342',is_active:'1'})-[r]-(p:Post{is_deleted:'0'})
WHERE type(r) in ['CREATED', 'FOLLOWS' , 'KEYWORD']
```

I didn't follow all your conditional statements (and I think you might be able to remove some of them once you convert it to pattern matching), but once you have your initial pattern you can add in whatever conditional statements you need. Example:

```
WHERE (p.post_type = '1' OR p.post_type = '4')
  AND (r.own_status = '1' OR r.follow_status = '1')
  AND NOT r.is_blocked = true
```

For more on pattern matching, check out section 2.9 of the Neo4j [Cypher Manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/syntax/patterns/).